# Lock Database in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

i have a SQL server with 2 databases in it. The Customer writes down his data in the first DB. The second is for the supplier. Now i wouldlike to lock the supplier database programmatically. The goal is to inhibit the Customer when starting the SQL management studio to read and write the data of the second Database while reading and writing in the first DB is not inhibited. But i don't know if it is even possible to realise that. If it is, how could it be realised programmatically with c# when creating the second DB.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're a few front-ends short of an application if you're letting customers use SSMS.  That said, you're talking about basic permissioning.  You can write some procedures to add and revoke the access you require and call them from your C# as needed

Comment: Question is not clear... what actually you need if data is no two different db  what is need of lock....

Comment: When starting the ssms and logging in i see the two databases. Then when clicking on the customer DB nothing is inhibited, but when clicking on the supplier DB the data shouldn't be seen or encrypted or a dialogbox with a needed password pops up. I was thinking of stuff like that. IS that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible to protect your databases using accounts but you can't expect SSMS to present a user interface to your liking.  It is what it is.  If you don't like it you need (and should!) create another interface onto the database to let your various classes of users in to the database & data they need to see